# How to convert Stream<String[]> to Stream<String>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I am trying to flatten my String[] stream to a String Stream

E.g.

```
{ "A", "B", "C" }, {"D, "E" } to "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).map(a -> a.split(" "));
```

`Files.lines(path)` returns `Stream[String]` and I split every string by " " to get an array of all the words ( so now `Stream<String[]>`.

I would like flatten each array of words into individual elements , so `Stream[String]` instead of `Stream<String[]>`

When i use flatMap instead of map I get an error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to Stream<? extends Object>`

I thought `flatMap` is used for this purpose? What's the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do

---

Question from professor:

Using streams : Write a method to classify words in a file according to length:

```
public static Map<Integer,List<String>> wordsByLength(String file) 
throws IOException {
   // COMPLETE THIS METHOD
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> <R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper);
> ```

A [`Stream#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) mapper expects a `Stream` to be returned. You are returning a `String[]`. To turn a `String[]` into a `Stream<String>`, use `Arrays.stream(a.split(" "))`.

The complete answer to your assignment:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> wordsByLength(String file)
        throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
                .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.split("\\s+")))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you pass to `flatMap` must return a stream, not an array.

e.g.

```
.flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.split(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `.flatMap()` operation :

- after the normal `.map()` operation

  ```
  Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).map(a -> a.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream);
  ```
- combined with normal `map` operation:

  ```
  Files.lines(Paths.get(file)).flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a.split(" ")));
  ```

---

At the end you'll need

```
public static Map<Integer, List<String>> wordsByLength(String file) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(file))                      //Stream<String>
            .map(a -> a.split(" "))                          //Stream<String[]>
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)                         //Stream<String>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length)); //Map<Integer, List<String>>
}
```